# How to stop beamer generating bookmarks

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I try that

```
\usepackage[bookmarks={false}]{hyperref}
```

But I receive error message

**"Hyperref option clash"**

So I instead that

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarks={false}}
```

But it doesn't work.

Is that `beamer` class conflict with `hyperref` package?

Comment: you probably have another package or the document class loading the hyperref package. compilable MWE would help here. However you could try adding before your `\documentclass{}` call the line `\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Page 18 of the manual:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={bookmarks=false}]{beamer}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `beamer` class doesn't conflict with the `hyperref` package, but it already loads that package with different options. You could use `\PassOptionsToPackage` to specify options before the class and `hyperref` are loaded:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks={false}}{hyperref}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I would expect that. However, the OP tried that. Furthermore, I mentioned this general approach because it could be used for other packages, which don't provide such a convenient `\...setup` command as `hyperref` does.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: What does work however is the following: `\PassOptionsToClass{hyperref={bookmarks=false}}{beamer}` (before the `\documentclass` command of course). This makes it possible to disable the bookmarks without touching the `\documentclass` call directly.